# how do i call java class object from javascript function?(with out ajax)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

java -> server side
javascript -> client side.

in ajax, we declare `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` in javascript.

and XMLHttpRequest is a class file(.java), and the javascript call(`xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`) would make an operation on java file too? right?
so,, what is a path code for javascript to build a constructor on XMLHttpRequest.java 
any one could explain to me if i am wrong..

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow what you're trying to do. XMLHttpRequest is not a Java class, and `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` is not a Java constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. XMLHttpRequest() is not java class it's Web API which was developed my Microsoft and has been adopted by all the latest browser to provide ajax support.
2. If you want to call java class object from java script than the only way i know is JavaScript Native Interface (JSNI), it can only be used with GWT(Google Web Toolkit) framework. As GWT compiles java into javascript, which makes it calling java object from javascript possible.

Hope this answers your question if not kindly let us know what exactly you are trying to achieve, would be able to help you better way.